# Firefox developer tools, open Inspector & debugger at same time

Tags: debugging, firefox, web-inspector, web-developer-toolbar

I'm adding content to the page using JavaScript and want to step through the code and see the tags being added to the HTML.

In Firefox developer tools, how can I make it so both "Inspector" and "Debugger" are visible at the same time. I don't mean the tabs, I mean the content that they show.

I know you can use the "Toggle Split Console" button to see the Console and Debugger at the same time, that's not what I want. I want the Inspector and Debugger, not the Console and Debugger.